# Prevent Bootstrap Modal close on Esc key press

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using NGX Bootstrap modal in my project. Inside the modal i have a form, right now if I press Esc key the modal is hiding.

How can I be able to show child modal(confirm modal) if any user is filling up the form and suddenly press the esc key or tries to close the parent modal.

Is there any way to show the child modal without closing the parent modal based on some condition if anyone presses the esc key.

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="parentModal.show()">Open parent modal</button>

    <!-- parent modal -->

    <div class="modal fade" bsModal #parentModal="bs-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-nested-name1">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 id="dialog-nested-name1" class="modal-title pull-left">First modal</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="parentModal.hide()">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
               <div class="form-control">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="email" />
               </div>
               <div class="form-control">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="password" />
               </div>
               <button type="submit" class="btn-primary"></button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

   <!-- confirmation modal --> 

    <div class="modal fade" bsModal #childModal="bs-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-nested-name2">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 id="dialog-nested-name2" class="modal-title pull-left">Second modal</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="childModal.hide()">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Are you want to exit? Your changes will not be saved.<br>
            <button class="btn-danger">Discard</button>
            <button class="btn-primary">continue</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using ng-bootstrap.

While using modal.open method you can pass keyboard attribute as false.

Its official doc can be found at :- 
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api

Eg:- `this.ngbModal.open(content, {keyboard: false});`

Comment: Yes I am using Ngx Boostrap and i am using directive approach. Now I have keyboard : true. Can i prevent closing of the parent modal on esc key press on a specif condition?(if any unsaved changes prevent closing on Esc and show child prompt modal)

Comment: make your ngbModal.close conditional?

Comment: i have tried with onHide() but it now working, i think it firing when the modal is closing. Any way i can show the child when i pressed esc from parent modal.